# Can you process a credit card on a mobile website

Tags: mobile-website, payment, credit-card

All,

This might seem like a silly question, but let's say I develop a mobile website. For instance, a website for a pizza parlor which can be viewed on a mobile phone. Can I process credit cards like you do on a "normal" website. In other words, can I do e-commerce on a mobile website? If not, why? If I can, is it the same as creating a shopping card and having the user enter their credit card information and process it, like we do when we buy something on line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand a bit on the other answers, yes...

You would redirect away from your pizza site to a page hosted by a payment service provider. That page would capture the card details over SSL, ensure funds are available / card is valid / etc, then redirect back to your pizza site with either a 'payment accepted' type response or 'invalid card' type response.

Where the card is accepted then the gateway will also generally return a 'token id' which you would store against the order. This token id is a reference to the payment details should you need to query anything, (or perform a refund for example).

There are a good number of q&a's regarding integration with payment service providers already on this site which would probably help further.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Providing the mobile browser supports SSL then it's perfectly doable.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to solve couple of problems.

-cookies/sessions may not work on all phones/networks
-ssl may not work properly on some phones/networks. especially ones that proxy users connection to the internet

you can also try billing companies like bango.com (though they ask for large amounts of money! per month)